# How to update ServiceNow table using jboss fuse connector

Tags: jbossfuse, connector, servicenow

Input JSON to REST API

```
`{
    "userName" : "UserName",
    "password" : "Password",
    "instance"  : "Instance Name",
    "table":"incident",
    "sysId": "9d385017c611228701d22104cc95c371",
    "model":"{'assigned_to':'681b365ec0a80164000fb0b05854a0cd','urgency':'2','comments':'Elevating urgency, this is a blocking issue'}"
}`
```

Processor contains following headers :

```
`    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put(ServiceNowConstants.ACTION, ServiceNowConstants.ACTION_UPDATE);
    headers.put(ServiceNowConstants.RESOURCE, "table");
    headers.put(ServiceNowConstants.TABLE, msg.getTable());
    headers.put(ServiceNowConstants.SYSPARM_ID , msg.getSysId());
    headers.put(ServiceNowConstants.MODEL, msg.getModel()); 
    exchange.getOut().setHeaders(headers);`
```

Spring Camel Context Bean File has endpoint:

```
`servicenow://${header.instance}?userName=${header.name}&amp;password=${header.password}&amp;apiUrl=${header.apiUrl}`
```

Output:

```
`<h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
        <p>Problem accessing /servicenow/update. Reason:    
            <pre>model must be specified</pre>`
```

CamelServiceNowModel is mentioned as Class in documentation, however there is no implementation of same. Please do help so to place Model String/Class in right place to update in ServiceNow.

Comment: Can you include some information on how to set up a test jboss fuse setup to use this.  I'm very familiar with Servicenow, but not so much jboss.

Comment: Hi, please use the link and follow the steps :

Comment: https://developers.redhat.com/products/fuse/hello-world/#fndtn-karaf-runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As per the documentation of ServiceNow REST API, the POST/PATCH operations, the data is supposed to be sent in Body

   > > This is solved with below snippet
   > >     `Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
   > >     body.put("short_description", msg.getShort_description());
   > >     body.put("priority", msg.getPriority());
   > >     exchange.getOut().setBody(body);`
2. ServiceNowConstants.MODEL accepts the String (class Path)

   > > `headers.put(ServiceNowConstants.MODEL, "java.util.HashMap");`